# tough exponential product and sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(Here is a transcription of the image):

$$\dfrac{e^{k}-1}{k}x+e^{k}-1=\dfrac{e^{x+k}-1}{e^{x}}$$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC6H5.png)

I'm not sure how to start solving the equation in the figure

Comment: Please [don’t use 
images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem) instead of [typing your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) + look at [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question), and [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I've written out your equation using LaTeX - please check that it is correct.

Comment: Solving for $x$? solving for $k$? finding all pairs $(x,k)$ that work?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we are solving for $x$ this is how I would approach it

Notice $x=0$ is a root to the equation as

$\dfrac{e^{k}-1}{k}0+e^{k}-1=\dfrac{e^{0+k}-1}{e^{0}} \implies e^k-1=e^k-1$

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{e^{k}-1}{k}x+e^{k}-1-\dfrac{e^{x+k}-1}{e^{x}}$

$f$ is differentiable with

$f'(x)= {{e^k-1} \over k} - \frac{e^xe^x-e^x(e^{x+k}-1)}{e^{2x}} = .......= \frac{e^k-1}{k}+e^k-1 $ . Now that thing is just a number since our variable is $x$ so it is either possitive , negative or zero.

We know $e^k \geq k+1$ and the "=" for $k=0$ but since we know $k \neq 0$ because it was on the denominator on the original equation we get that $e^k> k+1 \implies e^k -1 > k \implies \frac{e^k-1}{k}>1 $

Using the same logic we can see that $e^k-1>x$

So we have that $f'(x) \neq 0 \implies f$ is always increasing or always decreasing .

In either case $x=0$ is the only answer !

Comment: Ahem. I do not think that $x=0$ is the only answer. For instance if $k=1$ then $x=-1$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For $x,k\neq 0$ the equation is equivalent to
$$\frac{e^k-1}{k}=\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$$ with the evident solution $x=-k.$ To see that it is the only one non zero solution observe that $f(x)=\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$ with $f(0)=1$ is continuous and is strictly decreasing since $1+x< e^x$ for all $x\neq 0$. Furthermore $x=0$ is also a solution for all $k\neq 0.$